# What's the point of a Linux character device driver if you can just use outb/inb from userspace?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm having a hard time understand when I should write a device driver instead of just sending opcodes directly to the hardware via `outb` from my userspace programs. I initially figured that I should create simple routines for the hardware, but now I'm starting to think that algorithms should stay in the userspace.

Suppose I'm programming a hypothetical robotic arm. I could write several functions in a Linux kernel module that would automate the hardware outputs needed for common tasks (e.g. move arm to HOME position, pickup new block from known location at start of assembly line, etc.). However, after reading more about device drivers, it seems that rule of thumb is to keep the device driver as close to hardware-specific code as possible, leaving the "heavy lifting" algorithms to userspace.

This confuses me, since if the only functions implemented by the device drivers are simple opcode calls, what's the reason for a userspace program to use the device file instead of calling `outb`/`inb` directly?

I suppose what I'm trying to figure out is: how do I decide what functionality goes in kernelspace instead of userspace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question. I've wrestled with that - I've even written drivers to control robotic arms, when I knew for a fact it was not necessary. I could just as easily send commands thru a serial port, or outb(), etc. I only wrote those drivers for educational purposes.

There are a lot of good reasons for a device driver. Imagine trying to control your network card directly from userspace! First of all, a driver gives you a nice abstraction at the OS level (eth0, etc). But trying to handle interrupts for packet send/receive in userspace would be wildly impractical from a performance standpoint - maybe even impossible. Just the time it takes to respond to an interrupt in userspace would drag the interface to its knees.

Imagine further that you bought a new network card. Wouldn't it be nice to just load the new driver and continue talking to eth0 from userspace with no changes to your code?

So, I would say "there is no point" in writing a driver if you don't see the need. I think the existence of drivers is driven by the need (as in the NIC driver example), not the other way around.

It sounds like for your app, outb() is going to be much more straightforward than creating a driver. In the end, I didn't even use my robotic arm drivers - just writing bytes to the serial port worked just as well - and only required a few lines of code ;-)

Answer (score 8):

If you use `outb` and `inb` in userspace, then your userspace will be x86-specific - the userspace `outb()` and `inb()` macros are implemented with x86 assembly.  On the other hand, if you write a kernel driver than your driver will work on any PCI-supporting architecture - the `inb()` and `outb()` functions in the kernel are implemented in an architecture-specific manner.  The kernel also gives you functions like `request_region()` to ensure that your IO ports don't clash with any other driver.

Furthermore, your userspace driver would need to run as root (or technically with the `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` capability, which is root-equivalent).  A character device driver in the kernel would mean that you can use the UNIX permissions on the character device file to control which userspace user can access the device.

Comment: +1 you covered all the most important points.

Answer (score 2):

A device driver must implement only the mechanism to handle the hardware (It does not matter the operating system).
All the *intelligence* of a solution must live in user-space.

Yes, you can do everything in user-space but:

- it is not re-usable; other user-space programs must re-implement the mechanism to gain access to the robotic arm (for example)
- bad performance; it depends on the application, maybe it is not a problem for a robotic arm (is slow), but it can be a problem for a network card, a disk, graphic card

So, for a robotic arm, you should implement the mechanism in the driver (move motor, get information from sensors). So, your program and other program can use the driver to make something clever with the arm. The clever stuff is done by the user-space program: paint the Gioconda, prepare a cake, to move dynamite carefully. The driver is the implementation of basic functions to allow its users to use the hardware.

But obviously, it depends on the hardware and context.